# How to configure neoconf.nvim to autocomplete for installed plugins?

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I'm currently writing a lua plugin and I can't figure out how to get neconf.nvim to autocomplete the library methods.
This is my `.neoconf.json` file

```json
{
  "neodev": {
    "library": {
      "enabled": true,
      "plugins": [
        "plenary"
      ]
    }
  },
  "neoconf": {
    "plugins": {
      "lua_ls": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "lspconfig": {
    "sumneko_lua": {
      "Lua.runtime.version": "LuaJIT",
      "Lua.workspace.checkThirdParty": false
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using LazyVim and I tried to make sure that neoconf.nvim and neodev.nvim were install properly, but autocomplete is still not working for installed plugins.

Comment: Here is an example you can check: https://github.com/rcasia/neotest-java/blob/main/.neoconf.json . Also my config https://github.com/rcasia/nvim. Hope this helps.

Comment: It unfortunately didn't work. What I'm trying to do is get auto-suggestions while working on a lua plugin.